# Avoid hardcoding XML in PHP for an API request

Tags: php, xml, api

I'm sending the following XML to an api using cURL:

```
$xml = "<request type='auth' timestamp='$timestamp'>
                <merchantid>$merchantid</merchantid>
                <account>$account</account>
                <orderid>$orderid</orderid>
                <amount currency='$currency'>$amount</amount>
                <card> 
                    <number>$cardnumber</number>
                    <expdate>$expdate</expdate>
                    <type>$cardtype</type> 
                    <chname>$cardname</chname>

                </card> 
                <sha1hash>$sha1hash</sha1hash>
            </request>";
```

What is the best way to avoid hard coding this XML? I was thinking of using XMLWriter but seems strange as it won't be changing.

Should I use a template? Or generate it using XMLWriter / Simple XML?

Comment: You've got choices, there's not really an right answer to this: `XMLwriter`, `SimpleXML`, `DOMDocument` or even simply your own `String Appender .=`!

Comment: Which one would you recommend?

Comment: @MackieeE: String appender is not a *real* choice I'd say because this is often creating encoding problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, there's not necessarily a right answer to this but I recently had to write a project around an XML API Feed as well. I decided to go with `XMLWriter` and it's still *very* easy to interchange into others easily by using their respected `.loadXML()` functions.

```
class SomeApi extends XMLwriter {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->openMemory();
        $this->setIndent( true );
        $this->setIndentString ( "&#09;" );
        $this->startDocument( '1.0', 'UTF-8', 'no' );
        $this->startElement( 'root' );
    }

    public function addNode( $Name, $Contents ) {
        $this->startElement( $Name );
            $this->writeCData( $Contents ); 
        $this->endElement(); 
    }

   public function output() {
        $this->endElement();
        $this->endDocument();
   }

   //Returns a String of Xml.
   public function render() {
        return $this->outputMemory();
   }

}

$newRequest = new SomeApi();
$newRequest->addNode( 'some', 'Some Lots of Text' );
$Xml = $newRequest->render();
```

I think it's a nice clean way writing an XML Feed in PHP, furthermore as you can add internal functions such as:

```
$this->addHeader();

private function addHeader() {
   $this->addNode( 'login', 'xxxxx' );
   $this->addNode( 'password', 'xxxxx' );
}
```

Which then appends nodes that you'll use over & over again. Then if you suddenly need to use a `DOMDocument` object for example (As I needed too for XSL).

```
$Dom = new DOMDocument();
$Dom->loadXML( $Xml );
```

Comment: Write CDATA? For that? Most likely complete bloat, I wonder why you suggest so. Also why do you hide the responsibility to create XML behind the API name? The XML is most likely used in the protocol layer to communicate with the remote endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I use a template?

You actually already did use a template here.

> Or generate it using XMLWriter / Simple XML?

`XMLWriter` and also `SimpleXMLElement` are components that allow you to create XML easily. For your specific case I'd use SimpleXML for a start:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<request type="auth"/>');
$xml['timestamp'] = $timestamp;

$xml->merchantid = $merchantid;
$xml->account    = $account;
$xml->orderid    = $orderid;
$xml->addChild('amount', $amount)['currency'] = $currency;

$card = $xml->addChild('card');
$card->number  = $cardnumber;
$card->expdate = $expdate;
$card->type    = $cardtype;
$card->chname  = $cardname;

$xml->sha1hash = $sha1hash;
```

See that the XML is not hardcoded any longer, only the names used are. The SimpleXML library takes care to create the XML ([demo](https://eval.in/56606), here the output is beautified for better readability):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<request type="auth" timestamp="">
  <merchantid></merchantid>
  <account></account>
  <orderid></orderid>
  <amount currency=""/>
  <card>
    <number></number>
    <expdate></expdate>
    <type></type>
    <chname></chname>
  </card>
  <sha1hash></sha1hash>
</request>
```

Thanks to the library, the output is always valid XML and you don't need to care about the details here. You can further simplify it by wrapping it more, but I don't think this is of much use with your very little XML you have here.

Comment: @Phpdna: There is a difference between voting on an answer or voting on a user. You shouldn't do the later.

Comment: thanks, are there any major advantages in using SimpleXML over XMLWriter? I'm not sure which one to use.

Comment: How big is the XML chunk you create? If it's with the question, you can see the code-example in the answer here, I'd say that SimpleXML is a good fit for the job in your case. The interface of XMLWriter is not that compact and not that modular. DOMDocument is another alternative, however it's interface even more modular as SimpleXML is also more verbose so I'd say starting with SimpleXML here is a fine entry.

Comment: The XML is just slightly bigger, with another nested element. I gave your example a quick try but netbeans seems to be complaining about this line $xml->addChild('amount', $amount)['currency'] = $currency; It says my language version (5.3) doesn't support that syntax?

Comment: Yes that is PHP 5.4. For that variant, create an `$amount` variable as it was done with `$code`. Then use `$amount['currency'] = $currency;` on the next line.